# null error when using document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to to draw a circle using the canvas tag using javascript, but I am constantly getting an error stating `c is null` when using `document.getElementById()`. I initially assumed this was because of the HTML content not loading fast enough, so I used `window.onload` but this did not change anything. Any help would be appreciated:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" />

        <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <canvas id="myLogo" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = scripting();

function scripting() {

    logo();

    function logo() {

        console.log('called logo()');
        
        var c = document.getElementById("myLogo");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke(); 
    }
}
```

The above code results in the following error, referencing lines `12:13`:

[image]

Comment: `window.onload = scripting;` (no parentheses after `scripting`).

Comment: See also [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried moving your `<script>` block to the bottom of (last item in) `<body>` ?